# How to paginate on a parameterized list in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, parameters, paging

I want to paging in Product list with parameter Category, i using `PagedList` mvc
controller sample

```
   public ActionResult ListProduct(int id, int? pagePos)
        {
            var list = db.List_Product.Where(e => e.CategoryID == id);
            int pageNumber = (pagePos ?? 1);
            return View(list.ToList().ToPagedList(pageNumber, 2));
        }
```

and in view ListProduct.cshtml

```
@*@model IEnumerable<Sales.Areas.Users.Models.List_Product>*@
    @model PagedList.IPagedList<sales.areas.users.models.list_product> @*Maybe error in line here*@
    @using PagedList.Mvc

    <table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Name
        </th>
        <th>
            ID
        </th>

        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ID)
        </td>
    </tr>
    }   
    </table>

    Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount

    @Html.PagedListPager(Model, pagePos => Url.Action("ListProduct", new { pagePos }))
```

It's not working, and get this error `CS0234: The type or namespace name 'IPagedLis' does not exist in the namespace 'PagedList' (are you missing an assembly reference?)` although i had added reference `PagedList` ago.

Answer (score 0):

Without more informations about the error is hard to find the culprit. You should disable custom errors and activate debug in your web.config

First check that the variable id in ActionResult ListProduct is passed.

Then in your view change:

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<sales.areas.users.models.list_product>
```

With:

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<Sales.Areas.Users.Models.List_Product>
```

Comment: @brian uppercase/lowercase is important in C#

Comment: No, i'ad changed it but it's not efffect.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that all necessary namespaces come before the use of any types in that namespace

```
@using PagedList; //import this so we can cast our list to IPagedList (only necessary because ViewBag is dynamic)
@using PagedList.Mvc; //import this so we get our HTML Helper 

@model IPagedList<Sales.Areas.Users.Models.List_Product>
```

Comment: Dear @Nkosi, I try with you but it's not working for me.